# Using pyspark RDD .groupByKey extract highest value element per group

Tags: python, pyspark, grouping, rdd, top-n

```
TOKEN_RE = re.compile(r"\b[\w']+\b")
def pos_tag_counter(line):
    toks = nltk.regexp_tokenize(line.lower(), TOKEN_RE)
    postoks = nltk.tag.pos_tag(toks)
    return postoks

pos_tag_counts = text.filter(lambda line: len(line) > 0) \
    .filter(lambda line: re.findall('^(?!URL).*', line)) \
    .flatMap(pos_tag_counter) \
    .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[0][1], (x[1], x[0][0]))) \
    .groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1])))
```

I have a text file that was reduced to lines, than words, words were counted and tagged with a POS(part of speech) label. So what I have now is a series of tuples (pos, (word, count)). POS being the key. I need to find the most frequent word for each POS.

[('NN', (1884, 'washington')),
 ('NN', (5, 'stellar')),
 ('VBD', (563, 'kept')),
 ('DT', (435969, 'the')),
 ('JJ', (9300, 'first')),
 ('NN', (1256, 'half')),
 ('NN', (4028, 'season')),

This is my first pyspark project, so I don't think I am quite grasping the concept. I used group

[('VBD', 
  [(563, 'kept'), 
   (56715, 'said'), 
   (2640, 'got'), 
   (12370, 's'), 
   (55523, 'was'), 
   (62, 'snapped'),

Ideally the output would be - (POS, count, word) in any order as long as the tuple shows the highest count word per POS:

('NN', 1884, 'washington') 
('DT', 435969, 'the') 
etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea is `groupByKey`, then find the max value for each group. Since you need the longest word, you can define the key to the `max` method as length of the word.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('NN', (1884, 'washington')),
    ('NN', (5, 'stellar')),
    ('VBD', (563, 'kept')),
    ('DT', (435969, 'the')),
    ('JJ', (9300, 'first')),
    ('NN', (1256, 'half')),
    ('NN', (4028, 'season'))])

pos_count = rdd.groupByKey()
               .mapValues(lambda v: max(v, key=lambda x: len(x[1])))

print(pos_count.collect())
# [('DT', (435969, 'the')), ('VBD', (563, 'kept')), ('NN', (1884, 'washington')), ('JJ', (9300, 'first'))]
```

Comment: I don't need the longest word though, I need the most frequent one, so I would need the largest number in the tuple to play a role there, but you have definitely helped me a ton. So the solution would be    .groupByKey().mapValues(lambda v: max(v, key=lambda x: x[0])) for the last line

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the mapping step to `map(lambda x: (x[0][1], x[1], x[0][0]))` i.e:

```
pos_tag_counts = text.filter(lambda line: len(line) > 0) \
    .filter(lambda line: re.findall('^(?!URL).*', line)) \
    .flatMap(pos_tag_counter) \
    .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[0][1], x[1], x[0][0]))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the most frequent word per POS